# how can I merge an asp.net mvc app with android app

Tags: java, c#, android, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am working an E-commerce buy sale online asp.net mvc website. I am working in a group. we are beginners. we are confused about the fact that how we will be connecting an asp.net mvc app with java based android app? For example how android app will connect to the database which website is using. to be more specific how the same database will be synchronized with both platforms. kindly share the approach(s) to do that wisely. Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We can help with detailed questions but this is entirely too broad for an online forum.

Comment: As a heads up. The simplest answer lies in costructing a domain model which can be somehow applicable to both applications. Storing the data about it in some persistence(db), constructing an api around it and using that api in both applications. Or a completely different solution, with pretty much the same characteristics.

Comment: There is the server side and there is the client side. Your back end code(server side) would be your C#/ controllers/ database. Your front end code (client side) would be the pages/ html/ javascript. Your back end code is sitting in a spot where it can talk to the database.

Comment: if anybody have worked on it kindly share some clear information. 
however, @pijemcolu thanks

Comment: @belurd this question is a poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is here. Please abstain of recommending sites your not familiar with. See also: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, there is usually no "direct" conversion or merge between a MVC web site and a mobile app.

Your best bet *may* be to try to make the MVC site [responsive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) (i.e. Friendly to devices with different screen sizes) so that it can easily be displayed on a phone or tablet. You can then "merge" them that way. (I've never tried it personally, but a Web View *may* work here). So you'd achieve the "merge" by sometimes showing them your app code and sometimes showing them your mobile site (preferably as seamlessly as possible). Again, I've never tried that personally, but it's worth looking into whether that could work for you.

If you want to convert the code itself, the way you'd go about it is to first separate the server-side business logic from the client-side logic. The client-side logic (screen construction and whatnot) goes in the mobile device and the server-side business logic goes in a Web API RESTful service.

Comment: thanks for that great answer

Comment: @MuhammadYasirBilal Glad I can help